Disable comment function on Word Press when in Cyrillic
Lately I'm facing some spam messages on one of my Word Press blogs.
The comments are coming from different IPs all over the world, but what they have in common, they are all in Cyrillic.
Now, I was wondering if there would be a simple solution to disable the comment function as soon as a Cyrillic character is present in the text.
Could this be achieved via the ASCII char set? Let's say, I just want to allow 437, 850 and 852.
Preferable, I could add some simple code snipped and that's it.

Some regex ? Should work in PHP or JavaScript…

Do you have Akismet Anti-spam plugin installed and active?

I didn't test Akismet Anti-spam yet, but as far as I know it can't block Cyrillic comments in my described way, instead Akismet is a smart-spam filter, right? Okay, then I will try it with a regex.
